# How can I share timeout across tabs to only get fired once or block a timeout from being executed in another tab

Tags: javascript, browser, oauth-2.0, settimeout

In my SPA, I'm using a timeout to refresh a token before it expires. This timeout gets set once I land on the application based on the current stored token expiration time.

For example, if the token expires in at 12:00 AM, I do set a timeout to refresh the token at 11:50 PM.

Something like:

```
window.setTimeout(myFunc, token.expire - 10 minutes in MS);
```

If I have 1 tab for my application things work perfectly.

However, If I open 2 different tabs, and since the token is shared across the tabs by a cookie, both tabs will have the timeout set to fire at 11:50 PM, causing an error due to simultaneous requests and the token refresh request fails.

I'm trying to think how I can fire the timeout only in 1 tab, even if it's set to fire in the second tab at the same time.

Thinking like multi-threading here for example, what can I do to block the second tab timeout?

Can the session storage help in any way?

Any ideas would be very appreciated.

Comment: problem is, if you choose one tab to be the one that fires, then what if you close that tab? then the other one wont fire as you've chosen one already - one solution could be to use localStorage as a *mutex* - though, preferably, you'd fix this on the server side to that sending two (or more) requests at almost the same time doesn't break things

Comment: I would still have the timeouts for both tabs, but when the times comes, only 1 gets fired, so I'm kind of looking for a way to block the second one when it gets fired.

So if I close a tab, we are safe and the remaining tab will fire the timeout.

Comment: I guess using localStorage as a mutex won't be guaranteed always because by the time I set something in the localStorage, there is a big change that the second tab timeout if fired already.. Since both would be set to fire at the same second..

Comment: there's also BroadcastChannel - or perhaps even using serviceworkers - neither of which are available in older browsers of course ... as for *there is a big chance* - I'd say the chance is not as big as you'd imagine - even less by adding random milliseconds to the timeout :p

Comment: @JaromandaX didn't know about it, but looking at it now, it seems cool to communicate between tabs, also found other stuff interesting as well. Will see how I can use it to serve my purpose